# How does the Memory work when we use Polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, memory, polymorphism

There is kind of a similar blog but I'm interested from kind of a different view.

Consider these two classes

```
public class Parent {
    int x;

    public Parent(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    int y;

    public Child(int x, int y) {
        super(x);
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

In the main method

```
        Parent obj = new Child(1, 2);
        Child childObj = (Child) obj;
        System.out.println(childObj.x + " " + childObj.y);
```

If we look at this we can get our `x` and `y` back even though we started everything with `Parent` which can't store `y` at all (It has only `x` field as you can see).

When we create a `Child` object with `Parent` where does the extra variable `y` go (since the `Parent` can only store variable `x`)?

From my little knowledge there is a `Parent` in the stack referencing the `Child` in the heap, which saves `x`, `y` and the class from which the `new` was called.

Can you verify, deny, extend my idea?

Comment: Your assumption is correct so far: Only the reference on the stack has the type Parent, meaning it can point to all objects in memory which fulfill the interface/contract of that Parent type. It' doesn't really care about additional fields of the Child object in the heap.

Comment: `Parent obj = new Child(1, 2);` - shortly: is seen as `Parent`, but actually is `Child`.

Answer (score 1):

Java offers polymorphism only for reference types. That is, a variable of type `Parent` merely contains a reference to an object located elsewhere. The same reference can  refer to different objects over time, and these may be of different subtypes and sizes.

That is, when you do `Parent obj = new Child(1,2)` a single object of type `Child` is created, which stores the fields it inherits from its supertypes (`x`) in addition to the fields it declared itself (`y`).

When later accessing `parent.x`, the JVM reads the reference, and finds the corresponding object, and then proceeds to read its `x`. To simplify this process, most VMs keep the `x` field in the same place for all subtypes of `Parent`, so the VM can read the field the same way irrespective of the object's actual type.

Comment: Thanks. Could you describe the way the classes are stored in the memory? Is it exactly the way I described in the question? I've searched for this on web, but didn't find anything helpful.